# javafx: Strange effect when using StageStyle.TRANSPARENT for a pop up and breakpoint set in Platform.runLater

Tags: javafx, stage

I try to show a fully transparent circle

[image]

in a popup stage. With this code

```
public class Main extends Application {
    private Stage primaryStage;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            root.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.YELLOW, null, null)));
            Button b = new Button("Click me");
            b.setOnAction(this::OnClick);
            root.setCenter(b);
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);
            scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void OnClick(ActionEvent event)
    {
        Stage popup = new Stage();
        popup.initStyle(StageStyle.TRANSPARENT);
        // popup.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        popup.initOwner(primaryStage);
        popup.setAlwaysOnTop(true);

        VBox vb = new VBox();
        Scene scene = new Scene(vb);
        scene.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        popup.setScene(scene);
        vb.setBackground(new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.TRANSPARENT, null, null)));
        ClassLoader cl = Main.class.getClassLoader();
        Image image = new Image(cl.getResourceAsStream("images/TranspRedCircle.png"));
        ImageView view = new ImageView(image);
        view.setFitHeight(image.getHeight()/4);
        view.setFitWidth(image.getWidth()/4);
        vb.getChildren().add(view);
        popup.show();
        Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int i = 0; // set breakpoint here
            }
        });
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

and a breakpoint set within `Platform.runLater`I see a strange effect in the UI (black square or nothing at all for the image (or Stage ?))

[image]

the desired appearance is

[image]

With `StageStyle.UNDECORATED` the appearance **at the breakpoint** is
[image]

Is this an aftereffect to the performance issue described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27039349/performance-of-stagestyle-transparent) ?

I use Java 1.8.201.

Comment: This is an effect caused by you blocking the application thread. You shouldn't do long-running operations on the application thread; otherwise the application freezes. Triggering a breakpoint on the javafx application thread has the same effect. I guess the rendering wasn't completed completely at the time the breakpoint triggers which is why you see an unexpected version as frozen rendering result...

Comment: So, you say that with StageStyle.UNDECORATED it is just luck that rendering completes before runLater starts ? 
Because this is what I always see in my environment.
And there is no way to tell runLater to wait until rendering is complete ?

Comment: The only thing I know of that comes close is [`Scene.addPostLayoutPulseListener`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/Scene.html#addPostLayoutPulseListener(java.lang.Runnable)), but it explicitly states that the listener is triggered before rendering... I don't know how exactly you'd go about modifying the rendering process in a suitable way. As of JavaFX 11 there doesn't seem to be a way of accessing this functionality from the public API...

Comment: In Java 8 (which I use) there is no such method for Scene.